# Reading a PDF File From a SharePoint Library Using iTextSharp

Tags: pdf, sharepoint, visual-studio-2013, itext

I need to read a PDF that is located in a SharePoint 2013 library.

I am able to read a PDF from a local folder, but not from the library.

Specifically, I need to search the text in the PDF for some keywords and then move the file from the current library to another SharePoint library based on a condition.

I also found that I am getting an error from the code below:

```
PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader("http://mysharepointsite.com/MyDocumentLibrary/MyFile.pdf");
```

The error is "The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized."

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When a `PdfReader` is instantiated with a URL it uses a [`System.Net.WebRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) object with the `Credentials` set to [`CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.credentialcache.defaultcredentials%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), the relevant lines ([from here](http://sourceforge.net/p/itextsharp/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/src/core/iTextSharp/text/io/RandomAccessSourceFactory.cs#l112)) are below:

```
WebRequest wr = WebRequest.Create(url);
wr.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
Stream isp = wr.GetResponse().GetResponseStream();
```

If you want to use the `PdfReader` as-is you'll need to manipulate the `CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials`. This is a read-only property, however, so you'll probably need to actually setup IIS to impersonate the currently logged in user.

Another option is to not use the `url` method but instead write your own code that either accesses the file system directly or downloads the file using your own authentication rules and deliver that PDF to the `PdfReader` constructor.

Ultimately this isn't an iTextSharp issue but an IIS/SharePoint/.Net issue. To troubleshoot more we'd need to know in what context this code is running. Is it a web server or a desktop app? Does the context of the app have permission to talk to SharePoint?

Comment: This is a visual web part in a SharePoint site page.  The context has permission to talk to SharePoint.  On the same page I have an asp:FileUpload control that uploads a local file to the same library I am trying to read a file from.

Comment: I know a lot about .Net and iTextSharp but my SharePoint knowledge is pretty much nonexistent. When you upload a file does the server save it to the file system or does the server make an additional HTTP request to ask SharePoint to store the file?

Comment: I believe it makes an additional request for SharePoint

Comment: Hopefully one of the SharePoint people will be able to help you. Otherwise, if whatever you're doing it able to save a file to an HTTP endpoint I'd assume that it would also be able to read a file from an HTTP endpoint, too. If possible, I'd try that and then passing the file's bytes into the PdfReader.

Comment: Some APIs allow to pass in an optional `ICredentials` object which is then used as Credential for the Web Request (`WebRequest.Credentials`) when provided. But this has to be done in the iTextSharp Library source obviously.